# Why does GHC have a stack for each thread?

Tags: haskell, ghc

It's my understanding that GHC gives each thread a stack. Why is this necessary? Doesn't GHC compile to CPS? Isn't a thread expressed concisely as a closure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several aspects to your question.

The key reference for the design decisions in the GHC runtime is the paper [''Runtime Support for Multicore Haskell''](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/parallel/multicore-ghc.pdf).

Recall that

> The GHC runtime system supports millions of lightweight threads
>   by multiplexing them onto a handful of operating system threads,
>   roughly one for each physical CPU.

And:

> Each Haskell thread runs on a ﬁnite-sized stack, which is allocated in
>   the heap. The state of a thread, together with its stack, is kept in a
>   heap-allocated thread state object (TSO). The size of a TSO is around
>   15 words plus the stack, and constitutes the whole state of a Haskell
>   thread. A stack may grow by copying the TSO into a larger area, and
>   may subsequently shrink again

GHC does not compile via CPS. Each thread make recursive calls, and they must allocate to the stack. By representing the stack as a heap-allocated object, things are made simpler.

A thread is more than a closure.

As a thread executes, it starts allocating to the heap and stack. Thus:

> The stack of a thread, and hence its TSO, is mutable. When a
>   thread executes, the stack will accumulate pointers to new objects,
>   and so if the TSO resides in an old generation it must be added to
>   the remembered set [of the GC].

Garbage collecting objects pointed at by stacks can be optimized to ensure GC takes place on the same physical thread as the thread.

> Furthermore, when the garbage collector runs,
>   it is highly desirable that the TSOs that have been executed on a
>   given CPU are traversed by the garbage collector on the same CPU,
>   because the TSO and data it refers to are likely to be in the local
>   cache of that CPU.

So, GHC has a stack for each thread because the compilation mandates that threads have access to a stack and a heap. By giving each thread its own stack, threads can execute in parallel more efficiently. Threads are more than "just a closure", since they have a mutable stack.

Comment: You have done a great job of answering "how does ghc manage threads?", but the question specifically asks "why?". I assume that it's to do with performance, but would you care to elaborate.

Comment: It is always performance - GHC's execution model tries to minimize contention by threads for shared objects (to take advantage of purity). Since a stack is required by the runtime, per-thread stacks are an obvious step.